# Use of uncaught_exception to handle error conditions

Tags: c++, exception, uncaught-exception

I have following problem.

I have database connection that are recycled (put back into pool).

For example:

```
{
 session sql(conn_str); // take connection from pool

 sql.exec("insert into ...")
} // at the end of the scope return connection to pool
```

However in certain cases recycling may be wrong - for example disconnect, or some other significant error.

So I want to automatically prevent from the connection being recycled. I want to
implement following technique using `std::uncaught_exception` - so the exec() function
would detect exceptions and prevent recycling:

```
session::exec(...)
{
   guard g(this)

   real_exec(...);
}
```

Where guard:

```
class guard {
public:
   guard(session *self) : self_(self) {}
   ~guard() {
      if(std::uncaught_exception()) {
        self->mark_as_connection_that_should_not_go_to_pool();
      }
   }
}
```

Now, I'm aware of http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/047.htm that does not recommend using
`std::uncaught_exception` on the other case I don't see any wrong with my code also,
the provides examples discussed.

Are there any possible problems with this code.

**Note:**

1. I want this change to be non-intrusive so that SQL backend would be able to throw and not check for every case if it is critical or not.
2. I don't want user to take any action about it so it would be transparent for him.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any advantage to your method over something more straightforward:

```
session::exec()
{
    try
    {
        real_exec();
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        mark_as_connection_that_should_not_go_to_pool();
        throw;
    }
}
```

If the verboseness of this solution bothers you, I will note that they haven't ripped macros out of C++ yet. I wouldn't prefer this version as it masks the underlying code and is kind of ugly.

```
#define GUARD try {
#define ENDGUARD } catch(...) { mark_as_connection_that_should_not_go_to_pool(); throw; }

session::exec()
{
    GUARD
    real_exec();
    ENDGUARD
}
```

Another possibility is to assume failure until success is achieved.

```
session::exec()
{
    mark_as_connection_that_should_not_go_to_pool();
    real_exec();
    mark_as_connection_that_may_go_to_pool();
}
```

Finally to answer the question of whether `uncaught_exception` will work as you've outlined, I will quote from Microsoft's documentation of the function:

> In particular, **uncaught_exception** will return **true** when called from a destructor that is being invoked during an exception unwind.

It appears to do exactly what you'd expect.

Comment: The reason I don't use this method is because it is much more verbose. So if you have two dozen functions that do the same thing, the "guard" is simpler and cleared way to solve such problem IMHO.

Comment: Also `std::uncaught_exception()` is standard function, may be not so commonly used as try/catch

Comment: Is there any particular scenario that makes use of `std::uncaught_exception()` problematic for this particular case?

Comment: @Artyom, I'm not aware of any but as you say this is a rarely used function. I've added a supporting statement to my answer.